# Apktool crashes with some folders called values-mccxxxx-mncxxxx

Tags: android, apktool

When i'm trying to compile some apks like `framework-res.apk`, or `FileExplorer.apk` i get the same error always

```
invalid resource directory name: /ApkTool/Decompiladas/MiuiFramework.apk/res values-mcc9998-mnc9999 
invalid resource directory name: /ApkTool/Decompiladas/MiuiFramework.apk/res values-mcc9466-mnc9999
```

I know that I can fix this error rename the folder with only three numbers, but with an `apk`, if I compile it renaming these folders the `rom` don't boot.

Is there some way to build the `apk` without rename these folders?

Thanks.

Comment: This is dirty, but maybe you can compile it without those folders, then rename the apk to a .zip extension, add those folders back, then rename back to an apk? (You didn't specify if the apk is signed or not.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the apk need decompile to see this kind of folders (values) and i can't add them in a zip file. The apk don't need be signed.

Comment: Ok you know that you can rename the apk extension right in file browser into a .zip and explore the contents, right? You can also add resources and change it back to apk, without compiling!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those aren't valid `mnc` or `mcc` values. You can see on the [Providing Alternative Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources) page that `mcc` ranges from 0 to 999, while `mnc` ranges from 1 to 999.

Based on the naming of the framework. It seems you are dealing with a MIUI framework. That means its entirely possible that MIUI modified the AOSP qualifiers to allow such values. This means that MIUI would have their own modified `aapt` from those changes which could handle those non-standard qualifiers.

I checked out `ResourceTypes.h` to see what data type `mcc` and `mnc` are.

```
union {
    struct {
        // Mobile country code (from SIM).  0 means "any".
        uint16_t mcc;
        // Mobile network code (from SIM).  0 means "any".
        uint16_t mnc;
    };
    uint32_t imsi;
};
```

As you can see they are both `uint16_t`. So our max value is `65535`. So we could easily store `9998` and more without modifying the qualifiers themselves. This points the problem towards the `aapt` validation.

If we look at `AaptConfig.cpp` of `aapt` we see the `parseMcc` and `parseMnc` methods which both have a variation of this check

```
if (c-val == 0 || c-val > 3) return false;
```

So basically any value greater than 3 digits is failed, thus giving you that error.

Now I don't know how MIUI utilizes those qualifiers but you have two options.

1. Build your own `aapt` from source removing that check. You will need this [commit](https://github.com/iBotPeaches/platform_frameworks_base/commit/739804024a84ab48db8996aeb71a3404b3698356), which adds support from other MIUI qualifier changes. To be safe. I would just build your `aapt` from my `platform_frameworks_base` [repo](https://github.com/iBotPeaches/platform_frameworks_base). Due to the constant adapting nature of `aapt`, applications are becoming harder and harder to recompile correctly. My fork of `aapt` removes some unnecessary validations. (I do this because if you are decompiling an apk, it has already been compiled once, so its not apktool to ensure 100% compatibility like newer `aapt` try to enforce).
2. Delete those directories `res/values-mcc9998-mnc9999` and `values-mcc9466-mnc9999`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and sorry the delay, i compiled my own aapt removing the check and i compiled miuiframework but the rom still don't boot, if i remove these folders happens the same.

Comment: @juliusssss You'll have to grab a logcat to debug this further. "Don't boot" isn't exactly helpful.

Comment: I decompile and compile MiuiFramework without any changes in the apk, then i replace it into the rom and i flash the rom, but the rom don't boot it stay in bootlogo. Sorry for not explaining well. I tested with differents aapt and apktools and always happens the same.